# How DMA Controller handles the Input devices like say Serial port

Tags: embedded, dma

So, what I have learned so far is that CPU programs the source address, dest address, word count and the direction to the DMA controller whenever it needs to transfer the data from say a harddrive. But in this example, the hard drive is just a dumb device, so it makes sense because harddrive can never initiate a data transfer.

But, what if we have connected the serial port where in certain instances we are going to get 8 bits of data. I know the DMA controller is used for large memory transfer, but say I want to do DMA for these 8 bits. But the device driver on the CPU cannot tell when the data is coming and it also can not tell how much data is coming because the serial port may send 8 bits or 16 bits or no data at all. So in this case who fills the DMA controller's count and memory addresses since the device driver is completely unknown when the data is going to come in.

Comment: *"so it makes sense because harddrive can never initiate a data transfer"* -- In general that is true of many peripheral devices.  The input from a HDD is *solicited* input; the data was requested by the CPU from the device.  Input from a communications device can be *unsolicited*; the arrival of data was not explicitly requested, but the device has to be read to prevent data overrun. *"But the device driver on the CPU cannot tell when the data is coming"* -- An interrupt notifies the CPU (or a handshake with the DMA controller) that data is available.

Answer (score 2):

Using DMA serial *input* is complicated when the incoming data is not a continuous stream or fixed length packets.  The exact details will depend on the specific UART and DMA controller, but generally, each character that arrives will be copied to the *next* location in the provided DMA buffer, and an interrupt will be generated by the DMA controller when the buffer is both half-filled and completely filled.

A single byte DMA buffer serves little purpose over using the UART's data avalable interrupt, and will simply delay byte processing by one character period.

If your DMA buffer were two characters long, you'd then get an interrupt for *every* character (one for the half transfer, and one for the full transfer), which solves the problem of partially filled buffers not being serviced, but does not reduce the interrupt overhead at all so offers little advantage over direct UART interrupt handling.  If your UART includes a FIFO buffer, that would be a better method of dealing with asynchronous serial input when only a small amount of buffering is required.

When a larger DMA buffer is used the interrupt rate is reduced, but when a buffer is incomplete you will not get an interrupt, and the data may wait indefinitely.  One solution to that problem is to implement a timeout mechanism whereby if the DMA interrupt does not arrive within a time period determined by the baud rate and buffer length, then the timeout handler retrieves all data currently buffered.  Such a mechanism requires care to avoid race conditions between the timeout and the DMA interrupt, and to  ensure that data arriving *while* the timeout is being processed is not lost, or that data retrieved by the timeout is not repeated when the DMA interrupt eventually arrives.

Comment: Thanks! Nice explanation.

Comment: @JigarAgrawal : You are welcome, but I refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment - specifically the part _"When shouldn't I comment?"_.  If the answer is that great, upvote and/or accept it.